# Find and replace strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi I want to find specific terms within a dataframe values then replace them by matching with dictionary keys.

The dataframe:

```
    Search         term               Application
safe high school   trip                1
spring break       trips               2
gap year           trips               1
```

I have a list of words that I want to replace in a dictionary, keys are the terms to find then replace by the values.

```
{'high school': ['high-school'],
'spring break': ['spring-break'],
'gap year': ['gap-year']}
```

Idea output:

```
    Search         term               Application
safe high-school   trip                1
spring-break       trips               2
gap-year           trips               1
```

I cannot find a way to replace part of the string within a dataframe value so at the moment I read dataframes as strings

```
with open('df.csv','r',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    s = f.read() + '\n'
```

then using str.replace to replace them one by one like this, it does the job but inefficient.

```
s = str.replace(s, 'gap year', 'gap-year')
```

If there is a way to replace spaces in specific terms by "-", then using dictionary is unnecessary

Thank you

Comment: try using the isin() method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change dictionary by remove lists and then [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True` for replace substrings:

```
d = {'high school': 'high-school',
     'spring break': 'spring-break',
     'gap year': 'gap-year'}

df['Search term'] = df['Search term'].replace(d, regex=True)

print (df)
             Search term  Application
0  safe high-school trip            1
1     spring-break trips            2
2         gap-year trips            1
```

Comment: Thank you for the replace. About remove lists from dictionary, may I ask how to do it? I created the dictionary by converting from dataframe. D = word2.set_index('To_replace').T.to_dict('list')

Comment: @takkyi83 - What is `print(word2.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 116 entries, 0 to 115
Data columns (total 2 columns):
To_replace    116 non-null object
By            116 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 1.9+ KB
None

Comment: Then use `D = word2.set_index('To_replace')['By'].to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.replace` with `regex=True`

**Ex:**

```
to_replace = {'high school': 'high-school','spring break': 'spring-break','gap year': 'gap-year'}
df["Search term"] = df["Search term"].replace(to_replace, regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Search term  Application
0  safe high-school trip            1
1     spring-break trips            2
2         gap-year trips            1
```